# How to start another activity in function? Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            val navigate = Intent(this,Activity2::class.java)
            startActivity(navigate)
        }
    }
}

fun switchActivity(){
    val navigate = Intent(this,Activity2::class.java)
    startActivity(navigate)
}
```

I want to start an activity from a function and not from the main activity..
I can start an activity from main class but in function, the code doesnt work..
Please help.. I'm new to kotlin android programming..

Comment: why are you starting another activity inside `setContent { ... }`? it should, as the name implies, set the content...

Comment: actually there is a button to start another activity.. i just omitted the button to summarize the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i don't get your question clearly. But i'll try to answer your question based on my understanding of yours.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            switchActivity()
            // if you want to pass the class through the paramater,
            // can try this
            // TODO: Another Way
            // switchActivityCustom(Activity2::class.java)
        }
    }

    fun switchActivity(){
        val navigate = Intent(this, Activity2::class.java)
        startActivity(navigate)
    }

    // TODO: Another Function
    // fun switchActivityCustom(destination: Class<*>,){
    //    val navigate = Intent(this, destination)
    //    startActivity(navigate)
    // }
}
```

And the last one is, put your function inside the class (in this case: MainActivity Class)

Answer (score 0):

Just use it

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        switchActivity()
    }
}

fun switchActivity(){
    val navigate = Intent(this@MainActivity, Activity2::class.java)
    startActivity(navigate)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your function is declared at the top level, without a reference to `this`, you'd need to pass an instance of `Activity` to your function:

```
fun switchActivity(activity: Activity) {
    val navigate = Intent(activity, Activity2::class.java)
    activity.startActivity(navigate)
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer..
i followed your instruction and startActivity(navigate) gets an error
it says type mismatch, 
required: context
Found: intent

Comment: Actually, the correct way to call `startActivity` here would be through the `activity` reference, I updated my answer!

Answer (score 0):

**You can also try like this**

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        
        nextActivity(this, MainActivity2())
    }


    private fun nextActivity(context: Context, activity: Activity) {
        startActivity(Intent(context, activity::class.java))
    }
}
```